# Sudden Named Pipes Provider Error 40

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, web-config, iis-6, named-pipes

I'm trying to deploy a new build of an ASP.NET site to IIS 6. The current build of the site works fine. However, whenever I deploy the new build, I get the Named Pipes error. There are a few code(logic) changes, but nothing to do with data connections, and the web.config files in the two builds are identical. Any idea as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Is this a new server?  Sounds like the web.config is pointed at the wrong DB instance, a firewall problem, or the browser service is blocked (no port resolution).

Comment: No, the server has been up for a while now, and earlier deployments ran fine. The Web.config is pointed at the same DB instance as the last deployment. Can pretty much rule out firewall/browser service issues (I assume at least), because the site has been running fine thus far.

Comment: I find it odd that you get a named pipes connection error.  Your application is most likely using TCP.  When TCP fails, named pipes is the next protocol in line, which also failed.  This leads me to believe this is a firewall/port issue..  I would open ODBC and try to connect to the db/server listed in the web.config.  If you succeed firewall/port is ruled out.  If you fail, you know it's not your application.

Comment: Thanks for your help and suggestions. It turns out that in the 100 times I looked over the web.config I still didn't comb through it thoroughly enough. Somehow, I didn't notice that the new deploy was connecting internally(hosted locally) (diff ip, same DB instance), while the the current deploy was reaching out externally since it's not hosted locally. Sometimes you just need a second set of eyes :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, it turns out that the new deploy was connecting internally(hosted locally) (diff ip, same DB instance), while the the current deploy was reaching out externally since it's not hosted locally(data center). Exact same server, but hit with different IPs.